# Obtain records between two dates listed with entity framework in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the Entity-framework in C# and have a table named "service" and my column name is "tarikhservice" that shows the date. I want to ask how can I access all records that are inserted into my DB between specified two dates?

Comment: this could have easily been had by using search engines...

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is very late but I though it could help some one,
what about using:

```
 var result = context.EntityName
             .Where(entry => entry.DateField >= StarDate.SelectedDate.Value)
             .Where(entry => entry.DateField <= EndDate.SelectedDate.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var result = context.YourEntityName.Where(entry => entry.DateField >= minDate && entry.DateField <= maxDate).ToList();
```